# Duplicate values in an int array (best performance)

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, language-agnostic, duplicates

I have an array of numbers that have some duplicate values.
I want to find the first two duplicate numbers.

The real problem is it must be in best performance and I cant use `LINQ` it must be in classic codes.

The real question is about best performance so it means best answer is the fastest language and fastest algorithm.

I tried it in C#:

```
        int[] numbers = {5, 2, 10, 18, 55, 100, 10, 50, 23, 6, 14, 25, 12};
        int result1 = -1;
        int result2 = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] == numbers[i] & i != j)
                {
                    result2 = j;
                    result1 = i;
                    J = numbers.Length;  //this will cause loop exit.
                    i = numbers.Length;  //this will cause first loop to exit.
                }
            }
        }

        Console.Write("The result of search is {0} and {1}", result1, result2);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I will appreciate any answers ;)

Comment: How large is the array in practice and how are duplicates typically distributed?

Comment: Use `break` to cause the loop to exit, it is much more readable.

Comment: @NeilMacMullen array's length is about 500 and duplicates are about 5 numbers.

Comment: you can also do this with one loop.

Comment: Rollback the edit. Code after the break is not executed, so it now looks for the last duplicate instead of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the numbers and where you found them, and when you find one that exists in the dictionary, you have your duplicate and its position. Adding and locating items in a dictionary are O(1) operations, so the algorighm is an O(n) operation:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 2, 10, 18, 55, 100, 10, 50, 23, 6, 14, 25, 12 };
Dictionary<int, int> found = new Dictionary<int,int>();
int result1 = -1, result2 = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
  int number = numbers[i];
  int pos;
  if (found.TryGetValue(number, out pos)) {
    result1 = pos;
    result2 = i;
    break;
  }
  found.Add(number, i);
}
Console.Write("The result of search is {0} and {1}", result1, result2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

For some additional performance you can preallocate space for all the items in the dictionary that it might need. This uses more memory in the average case, but keeps the dictionary from repeatedly allocating more space when it grows:

```
Dictionary<int, int> found = new Dictionary<int,int>(numbers.Length);
```

Comment: It's perfect;). I test it with a stopwatch and the result was amazing. my code done in 0.4638 MS and your code done in 0.1001 MS

Comment: Is there any structure like Dictionary in c++? Is there any way to implement it in c++ like this ?

Comment: @HaMeD: That would be an `std::unordered_map`, so it would be possible to implement the same thing in C++.